# C# Dictionary ContainsValue look up by object attribute

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary

I have  `Dictionary<long, Location> PostalCodes` .

While i m adding new elements to this Dictionary I want to make a lookup to this dictionary and if the `Location.PostalCode` is not in this dictionary, I want to insert it. Otherwise I want to skip it. So , need to know if the PostalCode is already in the Collection. Cant use it as the key.

How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: So, your dictionary is named `PostalCodes`?  What does the long key represent?  What data is in the location?  Normally, if you want to add an item to a dictionary if it doesn't already exist at a particular value, you use that value as the key: `PostalCodes[postalCode] = location;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you need another dictionary which *does* use it as the key - basically a bidirectional map. At least, that's if you want it to perform well. You *could* just look through every value in the map, but that would be an O(n) operation.

(Alternatively, if you're doing this once, just create a `HashSet<Location>` for all the locations you're using. You don't actually need the `long`, by the sounds of it for the purpose of the *reverse* lookup.)

Comment: Long is for External Location ID, it s a pointer to map the IP with Locations. So i have to use that. Also, I cant really use Postal Code as the key value of the Dict. because, I have seen that postalcodes are not unique for location. at least that s what the providers file shows.

Comment: But you *don't* have to use the long for the reverse lookup - that's what I meant. Will edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
if(PostalCodes.Values.All(l=>l.PostalCode != location.PostalCode))
{
    PostalCodes.Add(key /*what is it*/, location);
}
```

But this might get slow with large amount of data.